# Get save checkbox values in haml even if submit button not selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, haml, onchange

This is SaaS ("Rotten Potatoes") training question that has been discussed many times last year but I don't seem to find answer to this.

I have a form with checkboxes for ratings that generate hash named ratings. Then I uses params[:ratings] to pass latest checkbox selections to different pages. My code works correctly when user submits the form. But if they wander around without clicking the submit button then the latest values are lost.

I think that the latest values needs to saved whenever user checks/unchecks a checkbox, but don't know how.

I need to do this using haml and ruby, no javascript etc.

Comment: hi you need to provide some sort of code that we can look at

Comment: Trying to figure out how to post the code

Comment: removed code since it violates edx honor code policy

Answer (score 1):

In you're movies controller you have the instance variable @selected_ratings where you save all the current ratings.

```
if params[:ratings] != session[:ratings] and @selected_ratings != {}
  session[:ratings] = @selected_ratings
  redirect_to :sort => sort, :ratings => @selected_ratings and return
end
@movies = Movie.find_all_by_rating(@selected_ratings.keys, ordering)
```

And in the movies index, in the form_tag you have

```
= check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", 1, @selected_ratings.include?(rating)
```

Comment: Where do I get current ratings from? I thought params[:ratings] will have the current ratings.

I did something similar to what you have mentioned, except redirecting.

Still figuring out for to post my code

Comment: You need to display the ratings in a form_tag movies_path ... . After you submit the refresh button from the ratings, in params[:ratings] you will have all the ratings.

Comment: I need the ratings even if the the user doesn't submit. If he makes some changes to checkbox and then clicks on some other link instead of doing refresh, I still want the latest checkbox values.

Comment: Ohh, I think this is not possible :-? . I mean, not without javascript. Are you sure this is what you need?

Comment: I loose the latest checkbox values if user clicks on 'More about #{movie.title}' link without doing a refresh

Here is the link to the generated swb page - [link](http://chobi.herokuapp.com/movies)

Comment: This is the requirement - 

If the user explicitly includes new sorting/filtering settings in params[], the values stored in the session should not override them. On the contrary, the new settings should be remembered in the session.



I am trying to do without javascript because it is not discussed yet.

Comment: Then I can't help you. The session[:ratings] are set when you submit the refresh, without submitting I don't think is posible. Actually, the type of sorting is saved in session[:sort] or params[:sort], so you are not overridding the ratings. I think this is all you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness.

Requirement was that if the user closes the web page and comes back later then the previous selections should be available. So I did it with cookies and passed the test case.